# How to set MQRHF2 header via JMS API

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I using JMS for communicate with message queue. The message queue server is IBM Websphere MQ 7.5.0.5.

And now I need to set MQRHF2 headers to my messages. How to do this via JMS?

Comment: This seems to be documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031990_.htm).   Does that help?

Comment: `MQDestination.setTargetClient(WMQConstants.MQJMS_CLIENT_JMS_COMPLIANT)`